# Expected value of a die

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics, expected-value, means

In a game a fair die is rolled three times. If a 6 first appears on the first, second or third roll you receive £5, £2 or £1 respectively. If no 6 appears you receive nothing. If the game is fair, how much should you pay to play it?

And my working out:[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2FBj.png)

But apparently the answer is £1.23 and my answer is £1.33

What am I doing wrong? Could you please suggest?

Thanks,
Yasme

Comment: Please write your questions in text instead of linking to images.

Comment: How did you come up with your probabilities?  Why do you think that you win £$5$ with probability $\frac{1}{6}$?  Why do you think you win £$2$ also with probability $\frac{1}{6}$?  Remember... to win £$2$ you needed to have first rolled a non-six and *then* rolled a six.  Remember... to win £$0$ you needed to have not rolled a six, then not rolled a six, and then not rolled a six again a third time.

Comment: To have not rolled a six and then rolled a six... that happens with probability $\frac{5}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6}=\frac{5}{36}\neq \frac{1}{6}$.  Fix the rest of the probabilities similarly and then use the correct probabilities in the expected value calculation.  Next... it looked like you had a power of $2$ written there near the $E(X)$?  No... no powers of two involved here at all... you are thinking of standard deviations.  Lastly... $\frac{4}{3}$ is not equal to $1.33$, it is equal to $1.3333333333\cdots$ with neverending 3's.  Do not write equals signs when things are not equal.

Answer (score 2):

The question is ambiguous on this point, but it seems to be making the assumption that the game *ends* when you get a 6 on any roll.  This means that you can't assume a 1/6 probability of getting a 6 on the second or third roll, because there might not *be* one.  So:

- The probability of getting a 6 on the first roll is $\frac{1}{6}$.
- The probability of *not* getting a 6 on the first roll but getting one on the second roll is $\frac{5}{6} \times \frac{1}{6} = \frac{5}{36}$.
- The probability of *not* getting a 6 on the first or second roll but getting one on the third roll is $\frac{5}{6} \times \frac{5}{6} \times \frac{1}{6} = \frac{25}{216}$.

For an expected payout of $\frac{1}{6}(£5) + \frac{5}{36}(£2) + \frac{25}{216}(£1) = £\frac{265}{216} \approx £1.226852$.

A “fair” game means that your bet is equal to the expected payout.  But since you can't bet a fraction of a penny, the amount is rounded up to £1.23.

Comment: "*since you can't bet a fraction of a penny*" Since we are greedy we should round *down* and not up... otherwise our expected return is negative (*albeit small*).  If we were to play the game a few thousand times, that all would otherwise add up to a net loss for us.

Comment: @JMoravitz: True.  But the odds are *always* rigged to favor the house.   Even if only slightly.